# MPI stacks on MPI_Init (100% cpu usage)

Tags: c, mpi

I run this code on some machines but the program sticks on MPI_Init and one cpu per node reaches 100% of usage.

This happens when I run on node1, node2 for example. 
But when I run on node1, node3 the program runs successfully.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>

int comm_sz;
int my_rank;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  printf("Before init\n");
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  printf("After init\n");

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_sz);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  if(my_rank == 0) {   
    int proc_id;

    printf("*[%d] Hello world!\n", my_rank);

    for(int i = 0; i < comm_sz - 1; i++){
      MPI_Recv(&proc_id, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
      printf("**[%d] Hello world!\n", proc_id);
    }
  }

  if(my_rank != 0) {
    MPI_Send(&my_rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

And I run the mpi program on cluster with:

```
mpirun -H node1,node2 -n 2 main
```

When the programs run on nodes 1,2 the program prints only "Before Init" twice and then sticks on that with one cpu per node to reach 100% of usage.